# I have issue about my data visualization with map plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I want to show  how many mma fighters  each country has.This code is works. But USA has not any color.(USA has the greatest value)How can I fix it?

https://www.kaggle.com/firaterdemdogan/mma-practice

```
data = [ dict(
    type = 'choropleth',
    locations = index,
    locationmode = 'country names',
    z = values,
    text = index,
    #colorscale = [[0,'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],[1,'rgb(56, 142, 60)']],
    #colorscale = [[0,'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],[1,'rgb(220, 83, 67)']],
    colorscale = [[0,"rgb(5, 10, 172)"],[0.85,"rgb(40, 60, 190)"],[0.9,"rgb(70, 100, 245)"],\
        [0.94,"rgb(90, 120, 245)"],[0.97,"rgb(106, 137, 247)"],[1,"rgb(220, 220, 220)"]],
    autocolorscale = False,
    reversescale = True,
    marker = dict(
        line = dict (
            color = 'rgb(180,180,180)',
            width = 0.5
        ) ),
    colorbar = dict(
        autotick = False,
        tickprefix = '',
        title = 'Countries Of Fighters'),
  ) ]
layout = dict(
        title = 'Countries Of Fighters',
        geo = dict(
             showframe = False,
             showcoastlines = True,
             projection = dict(
             type = 'Mercator'
    )
)
)
fig = dict( data=data, layout=layout )
py.iplot( fig, validate=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- fundamentally country is not normalised to standard values
- have used https://restcountries.eu/#api-endpoints-name to get country ISO standard details.  It's not quick but it works
- now **mma** dataframe has two additional columns, **isocountry** - standardised name **iso3code** - standard 3 character code
- there are still some countries that do not normalize
- have not focused on formatting figures, just simple ones to demonstrate it works when country data has been standardised

```
import kaggle.cli
import sys, requests
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import plotly.express as px

# download data set
# https://www.kaggle.com/binduvr/pro-mma-fighters
sys.argv = [
    sys.argv[0]
] + "datasets download binduvr/pro-mma-fighters".split(
    " "
)
kaggle.cli.main()

zfile = ZipFile("pro-mma-fighters.zip")

dfs = {f.filename:pd.read_csv(zfile.open(f)) for f in zfile.infolist() }
mma = dfs['pro_mma_fighters.csv']

# country names are not clean...
def iso_dtl(c):
    cmap = {}
    res = requests.get(f"https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/{c}")
    if res.status_code==200:
        if len(res.json())==1:
            cmap = {"isocountry":res.json()[0]["name"], "iso3code":res.json()[0]["alpha3Code"]}
        else:
            df = pd.DataFrame(res.json()).sort_values("population", ascending=False).reset_index()
            cmap = {"isocountry":df.loc[0,"name"], "iso3code":df.loc[0, "alpha3Code"]}
    else:
        cmap = {"isocountry":c, "iso3code":""}
    return {**{"country":c}, **cmap}
dfcountry = pd.DataFrame([iso_dtl(c) for c in mma["country"].unique()])
mma = mma.merge(dfcountry, on="country")

px.bar(mma["isocountry"].value_counts()[:5]).show()

px.choropleth(mma["isocountry"].value_counts().reset_index(),
             locations="index", locationmode="country names", color="isocountry")
```

[image]